# ASP.NET MVC: How to allow some HTML mark-up in Html Encoded content?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-encode

Is there some magic existing code in MVC 2 to Html.Encode() strings and allow certain html markup, like paragraph marks and breaks? (coming from a Linq to SQL database field)

A horrible code example to achieve the effect:

```
Html.Encode(Model.fieldName).Replace("&lt;br /&gt;", "<br />")
```

What would be really nice is to overload something and pass to it an array (or object) full of allowed html tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing built in to ASP.NET or MVC for this, but it's not that hard to write your own whitelist-based one with regular expressions and so on. [Here's one that Jeff wrote](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/safe-html-and-xss/), though it's pretty rough around the edges...

Answer (score 5):

It's not a good idea to create your own whitelist based on regular expressions because you'll likely inadvertently open a security hole for XSS.

From Sanderson's book "Pro ASP.NET MVC3 Framework":  "...The only viable mitigation is strict, whitelist-based filtering: use a library like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) to ensure the user-supplied markup contains *only* the tags that you explicitly allow."

Sanderson goes on to supply a link to a site that demonstrates a broad range of XSS techniques that you'd have to test for if you use the regex approach. Check out http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of anything off the bat but I guess you could write an extension method that allows you to add a paremeter/list of items to allow.

```
Html.Encode(Mode.fieldName, List<items> Myitems);
```

It could modify the allowable tags into `&lt;` etc and then encodes the rest like normal.

Comment: The only problem with going like this is that if someone explicitly puts `&lt;br/&gt;` in their HTML (expecting it to display like that, rather than being converted to an actual new-line) will be surprised when it gets "unescaped" by your routine...